# MySQL foreign key constraint fail when executed

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert into my database however receiving the following error when the query executes:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_app`.`tbl_products`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_category` (`catid`))'

this is my code in c#

```
private void btn_prdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;  database=db_app; username=root; password=; port=8080";
        string Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_products.cat_id ( cat_id, prod_name, prod_quantity, prod_price, prod_desc) VALUES('" + cb_catname + "', '" + tb_prdname+"', '"+tb_prdqty+ "' , '" + tb_prodprice + "', '" + rc_prddescript + "')";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;




        conn.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (myReader.Read() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add Successfull!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }

        else if  (tb_prdname.Text == "" || tb_prdqty.Text == "" || tb_prodprice.Text == "" || rc_prddescript.Text == "" || cb_catname.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill up require", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        else
        {

        }

        
        conn.Close();
    }
```

[image: img]

**Table 1:**

[image: img]

**Table 2:**

![img] https://i.stack.imgur.com/IapVi.png

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DWOi.png)

[table relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um7qF.png)

Comment: Please provide your code and data as text rather than images. And I would *very strongly* recommend that you start using parameterized queries instead of building SQL dynamically - search for "SQL injection attack" for the main reason for parameterized queries, although there are other benefits too.

Comment: Note that we don't know what value you had for `cat_id`, which doesn't help. A [mcve] would make your question much clearer.

Comment: Server tells that you try to insert `tbl_products.cat_id` which is absent in `tbl_category`.